# conditionally filling the missing values based on the other variables available

Tags: python, pandas

How to conditionally use a column to fill in the missing values of the other column.

DF :

```
A   B   C
1   158 damage
nan 789 not damage
nan 898 damage
nan 698 damage
nan 445 not damage
0       not damage
```

Using column C, I want fill column A null values.

```
Condition, if C == damage, then A = 1 else 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['A'] = np.where(df['C'] == 'damage', 1, 0)
```

Or, more idiomatically:

```
df['A'] = (df['C'] == 'damage').astype(int)
```

Comment: I had to just fill in the nan's, in my case I have other variables in df['A]

Comment: @pylearner, Sure, then: `df['A'] = df['A'].fillna((df['C'] == 'damage').astype(int))`